# Why is there no atomic_{store,load} for weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, atomic, smart-pointers

Why does the C++ standard include an `atomic_store` or `atomic_load` overload for `shared_ptr`, but not `weak_ptr`?

Is this just an oversight, or is there an actual reason for not providing atomic operations for `weak_ptr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an oversight. There is a C++(17?) standard design proposal by Herb Sutter for atomic_shared_ptr/atomic_unique_ptr/atomic_weak_ptr, the document also explains the drawbacks of the existing approach with free funcitons atomic_load/atomic_store for shared_ptr: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4162.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the answer is because, in order to use a `weak_ptr`, you first convert it to a `shared_ptr` using `lock()`. Once you have that `shared_ptr` you can use the atomic operations.

Comment: What about the case where I have a `weak_ptr` that is assigned from two threads simultaneously? Without using atomic store/load, an object will potentially be smashed.

Comment: And while it might depend on implementation, a `weak_ptr` could participate in a reference count on the control block for the object. Once all `shared_ptr`s have disappeared, then any remaining `weak_ptr`s have shared ownership of the control block just like a `shared_ptr` normally has shared ownership of an object. So behind the scenes it's relevant whether or not `weak_ptr` assignment is thread-safe for the same reason it's relevant for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: There should really be an atomic version of `lock()`. I was convinced there actually was one, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I was under the impression that the refcounting semantics of `shared_ptr` were implicitly atomic, which suggests that taking a `lock()` on a `weak_ptr` is already safe. I don't have a handy reference to back that up at the moment though.

Comment: @KevinBallard: The atomic increments are for the following situation: Suppose you have pointers `p1` and `p2` in two concurrently running threads. Now in each of those threads, you can make copies `q1 = p1` and `q2 = p2`, and *that* preserves the consistency of the shared pointer. Nothing is said about accessing the *same* pointer from two threads at once.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not really qualified to talk about C++'s atomicity guarantees because I haven't studied up on that yet. But `lock()` returns a new `shared_ptr` initialized with the value of the original one, which itself is safe. The only question is whether accessing the `weak_ptr` from multiple threads to begin with is safe, and that I don't know.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Well, I think that's the entire point of the discussion, non? After all, by the exact same token you can argue that the shared pointer *copy constructor* returns a new `shared_ptr` initialized with the value of the original one. Yet we still have the dedicated atomic load and store operations.

Comment: @KerrekSB: My impression is the atomic load/store for `shared_ptr` have nothing to do with the refcounting semantics and everything to do with performing an atomic load/store on the underlying wrapped value. Since `weak_ptr` has to turn into `shared_ptr` before accessing the underlying wrapped value, and since the refcounting semantics is already atomic, I don't think there's a problem turning a `weak_ptr` into a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @KevinBallard There is a potential situation though where locking an `std::weak_ptr` results in an `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception, at least from a close reading of the Standard. Whether this is a defect (and `lock` really is meant to be a conceptually atomic operation -- either you get a null shared pointer or one pointing to the associated shared state) or intended is not known.

Comment: @LucDanton: `bad_weak_ptr` is thrown if you pass a `weak_ptr` that references a deleted object in as the argument to the constructor of `shared_ptr`. `weak_ptr.lock()` just returns an empty `shared_ptr` if the referenced object is deleted.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the atomic functions aren't used to operate on the underlying pointer (I don't see much reason for this, either). See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2632.html

Comment: @LucDanton: `std::weak_ptr::lock` is declared `noexcept`; it *cannot* throw. Neither can `use_count` or `expired`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Then that is evidence that `expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this)` as the specification for `lock` *is* a defect, isn't it? Perhaps some text adding that the effect should be 'as-if', but without the race condition is needed.

Comment: @LucDanton: No. That's not the exact implementation, where you could theoretically copy-and-paste it into your code. It's an explanation of what the code does, not *how* it does it. It describes the return value, nothing more. Just as `expired()` is not literally implemented as `use_count() == 0`.

Comment: @LucDanton: The cppreference.com description says "Effectively returns `expired() ? `...". The word "Effectively" there is a hint that this isn't an exact definition.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course it's not. But isn't an implementation that decides to model the same effects as the description (race condition included) conforming, strictly speaking? Isn't that what the notion of a library defect is for, as opposed to the intent of the Standard?

Comment: @LucDanton: I don't know about the question of race conditions; I was talking about your statement about *throwing exceptions*. Which `lock` is not allowed to do.

Comment: @LucDanton: That's actually a good point. I don't know what guarantees the standard makes. But libc++ certainly doesn't implement it using `expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this)`.